# How to display user_nicename and usermeta values by custom query in Wordpress?

Tags: sql, wordpress

I am trying to display user_nicename and one of usermeta values where meta_key is description. My query is given below:

```
<?php
$querystr = "
        SELECT * 
        FROM $wpdb->users, $wpdb->usermeta
        WHERE $wpdb->users.ID = $wpdb->usermeta.user_id 
        AND $wpdb->usrmeta.meta_key = 'description' 
     ";

$retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

?>

<?php global $retrieved_data; foreach ($retrieve_data as $retrieved_data){ ?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Customer Name</th>
        <th>Customer Details</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $retrieved_data->user_nicename;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $retrieved_data->meta_value;?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php } ?>
```

My final output should be displayed inside a table which will look something like below:
[image]

But I am in confusion how to do that. I am facing problem for both sql syntax and displaying data inside the table. Sorry for this easy question, I am still a learner. Can anyone help me in here? Thanks

Comment: There is a site for WordPress development questions : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: I know that. If I can't find the solution, then I will put the question in there.